# Print string character base on index input

Tags: python, string

I'm self studying the python language as a beginner for a few days now and i need some help regarding this question of mine.

I'm currently exploring on strings and writing simple programs about it. SO here's the problem. I want to write a program to print out specific string character by the input of index by the user. For example, the user input a string: "Hello" and the input of index, let's say: 3. Then, the program will print out the alphabet "l".

Here is my code but it is not working:

```
x= input("Enter a sentence:")
y= int(input("Enter an number:"))

for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i]==y[]:
       print(x[i])
```

I'm pretty sure my problem lies in the 5th line of the code but any correction of the code would be appreciated :)

Comment: I guess you meant `i == y` instead of `x[i] == y[]`

Comment: try if( i == y) at your 5th line

Comment: @ewcz  thanks! it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient pythonic solution for this problem should look like this.

```
x= input("Enter a sentence:")
y= int(input("Enter an number:"))

print(x[y])
```